# How do I center an image in a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimage

I use this code to create an image inside a cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    UITableViewCell *cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"] autorelease];


    switch (indexPath.row) {
    ...
    case 5:
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Search.png"];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

How do I center the image in the cell?  Do I HAVE to subclass UITableViewCell?

Comment: Learn to create custom tableCell, then you can place it anywhere you want.

Comment: I was looking for an option, but Ill have to go with this...thanks @iAn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better and efficient way to do this is using **Custom UITableViewCell**. So in feature, you can easily customize the TableViewCell.

You can do this through both code and Interface builder.

[Custom UITableViewCell Using Interface Builder](http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/05/24/custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder/)

[Customize Table View Cells for UITableView](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/)

Comment: Thx @Ramshad I guess ill have to go with a custom class

Comment: Ok Ive subclassed and created the XIB. Added the outlet and connected it in the xib/storyboard. I imported the custom cell class and changed the cell class in cFRAIP from UITableViewCell to MyCustomCell. I also set the tableview cells to MyCustomCell Identity and their identifiers. I have 5 static cells. What else do I need? Because Im getting just a blank cell for all 5 cells.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this if you don't use the provided cell.imageView but instead add a new UIImageView to the cell. Try something like this at the appropriate place in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
    UIImageView *newImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Search.png"]];
    newImageView.center = cell.center;
    [cell addSubview:newImageView];
```

Comment: This doesnt seem to work.  I get an "Expected expression error at the UIImageView line.

Comment: Interesting, it works ok for me. I think that error means you have a bracket or semicolon missing or in the wrong place. Even though the error is on the UIImageView line the problem may be on the line above it. If you can't find it, post your code and I'll see what I can find.

Comment: Well I went with the custom class cell...so Im dealing with a different problem now :)  But ill try your solution when Im done here, Ill snapshot back and try it and post back here

Comment: Nah, that's OK. The custom cell class is probably a better solution long term. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I know, this question was asked 10+ years ago, and the Swift syntax was very different, but just in case, if somebody finds it now (like we did, looking for the same thing),
here is what worked for us:

1. Create attributed string consisting of image only

   ```
    let image = ImagesForXTMTPositiveFunction (Dimension: DirectoryTable.ImageDimension)
    let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
    attachment.image = image
    let imageString = NSMutableAttributedString(attachment: attachment)
    myDirectoryTable.myAttributedDataSource.append(imageString)
   ```
2. When reloading tableView cells, center its content (line 3) and place the attributed string into cell label (line 4)

   ```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
    ........................
        cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        cell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center
        cell.textLabel?.attributedText = myDirectoryTable.myAttributedDataSource [indexPath.row]
        ........................
    }
   ```

Answer (score -1):

```
cell.imageView.center = cell.center;
```